# The point of view of semicats in functional analysis

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory

I'm completing a paper about (Mitchell's) semicats (well, not exactly, but let's say so for simplicity), and as a motivational example I'd like to mention at some point that the monic/epic morphisms of the semicat of real/complex normed spaces and (linear) compact operators between them (with the obvious source and target maps and the equally obvious composition) are exactly those that one is expected to get. So my question is:

> > Is there anything in the literature taking the point of view of semicats in the study of compact operators, in such a way that I can cite it (at least for the sake of comparison)?

Feel free to extend the same question to other objects of interest in functional analysis such as real/complex normed spaces and (strictly) contractive linear operators or (topological) pointed spaces and compactly supported base maps. I don't expect anything like Helemskii's *Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis*, but on the other hand I find it a little bit surprising that nobody has already tried to pursue this line of thought, and arguing that the reason for this "gap" may be due to the fact that "semicats are not really more general than cats", since "there exists a functorial way to turn them into a category", is just another instance of the principle of explosion.

**Added later.** [1] Loosely speaking, a semicat is a not-necessarily-unital category. For what it is worth, and to the best of my knowledge, the notion was first introduced by B. Mitchell in *The dominion of Isbell,* TAMS, Vol. 167 (1972), 319-331. [2] Monic and epic arrows in a semicat are defined in the very same way as monic and epic arrows in categories. [3] If necessary (though I don't think so): By a compact operator between $\mathcal K$-normed modules, where $\mathcal K = (\mathbb K, |\cdot|)$ is a normed [rng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-ring) (here, just a rng endowed with an absolute value), I mean a triple $f: \mathcal M_1 \to \mathcal M_2$ for which $\mathcal M_i = (\mathbb M_i, \|\cdot\|_i)$ is a normed (left) module over $\mathcal K$ and $f: \mathbb M_1 \to \mathbb M_2$ is a homomorphism of (left) $\mathbb K$-modules such that the image of any bounded subset of $\mathcal M_1$ under $f$ is [relatively compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace) in $\mathcal M_2$.

Comment: For the future: Please always use the tags with two letter prefix if (and only if) one exists instead of creating an essentially identical tag. Thanks in advance! 

Comment: I gather from the second example that semicats needn't have identity morphisms. Perhaps you could append the relevant definition?

Comment: Are the epics the operators with fin-dim codomain (hence surjective)?

Comment: @quid. Sure, sorry, I've just overlooked it. @Adam. Done. @Yemon. No, they're the compact operators with dense range (unless something is wrong in my arguments).

Comment: Btw, it is rather clear that at least all compact operators with dense range must be included, for there exists an obvious faithful (semi)functor from the semicat of real/complex normed spaces and compact operators to the usual cat of real/complex normed spaces and bounded (linear) operators (where epimorphisms are known to be all and the only bounded operators with dense range), and faithful (semi)functors reflect both monic and epic arrows (just like in the categorial case).

Comment: What is the difficulty in determining monics and epics? If an operator has non-trivial kernel, it kills some map from $\mathbb{R}$ and if the range is not dense, Hahn-Banach yields a non-zero functional vanishing on the range. Operators with finite-dimensional source or target are compact. This hardly needs a reference, does it?

Comment: @Martin. But nobody (apart from you) claimed that the question of characterizing monos and epis in the semicat of normed spaces and compact operators is "difficult" (whatever this may mean, and for sure it means nothing absolute or definite), and the question raised by the OP is different. So what is the point with your comment?

Comment: @Yemon. I'm probably missing something big here, but it is known, e.g., that for any separable Banach space $\mathcal X$ (over the real/complex field) there exists a compact (linear) operator $f: \mathcal X \to \mathcal X$ that is injective and has dense range; see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-05/S0002-9939-05-08084-6/S0002-9939-05-08084-6.pdf (Proposition 2.1).

Comment: @Salvo: my mistake, and an embarassing one given http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122504/compactly-generated-banach-spaces/122506#122506 [I've deleted the earlier comment.]

Comment: @Yemon. No need for feeling embarrassed: We're men, and have all the right to make honest mistakes. Btw, here is a possibly simpler construction: The linear operator $f:\ell^2(\mathbb R)\to \ell^2(\mathbb R): (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto (x_n/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is compact, injective and has dense range.

Comment: No immediate point, really. I suppose I'm puzzled about the beating around the bush with monics and epics in title, body of the question and the comments, while the question, as you say, asks something different.

Comment: @Martin. I've edited the title and added some more comments to clarify my point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You could be interested in reading about *operator ideals*. These give a vast number of interesting functional-analytic examples of "semicats" different from the compact operators.

Comment: Yes, of course, but we will agree that, though worth mentioning, this is not really different, in some sense, from the example of compact operators, all the more that it can be further abstracted by referring, say, to the ideals of an arbitrary cat.

Answer (score 2):

See:

Peter W. Michor: Banach-Semikategorien, I. Sitzungsberichte Österreichische Akademie Wiss., Abt II, 185 (1976), 181--204, MR 56#3644 a, ZM 359.46049. [(pdf of I)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/BanachSemikategorien-I.pdf)

Peter W. Michor: Banach-Semikategorien, II. Sitzungsberichte Österreichische Akademie Wiss., Abt II, 185 (1976), 205--219, MR 56#3644 b, ZM 359.46050. [(pdf of II)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/BanachSemikategorien-II.pdf)

Peter W. Michor: Banach-Semikategorien, III. Sitzungsberichte Österreichische Akademie Wissenschaften., Abt II, 185 (1976), 221--238, MR 56#3644 c, ZM 359.46051. [(pdf of III)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/BanachSemikategorien-III.pdf)

Johann Cigler, Viktor Losert, Peter W. Michor: Banach modules and functors on categories of Banach spaces. Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Mathematics 46, Marcel Dekker Inc., New York, Basel, (1979), MR 80j:46112, Zbl 411.46044. Review in Bull. AMS 3,2 (1980)
[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/banach_modules_and_functors.pdf)

Peter W. Michor: Functors and categories of Banach spaces. Springer Lecture Notes 651, (1978), vi+99 pp., MR 80h:46116, Zbl 369.46069. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/bookLN.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the references! I'm very interested, but unluckily for me, I cannot read German. So let me ask: Is there any hope that the material of the three papers of the series _Banach-Semikategorien_ has been _integrally_ included in the books mentioned in your answer? In other words, is there anything relevant in the papers that cannot be found in the books?

Comment: Sorry, nothing from the 3 papers is included in the books. 
The main thrust of the three papers are Banach semicategories with approximate units. The MathSciNet review was quite detailed, as I recall. 

Comment: Thanks, I will try to understand as much as I can (hopefully with the help of my German office mate).