# Schauder basis in the Arens-Eells space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Context**

*Arens-Eells space.* Let $X$ be a separable pointed metric space with base point $e$. An *elementary molecule* is defined as follows (Nik Weaver, Lipschitz Algebras, 2nd ed.)
$$
m_{pq} := \delta_p - \delta_q,
$$

where $\delta_p, \delta_q$ are delta-functions placed at $p,q$.
The Arens-Eells space $AE(X)$ (also known as the Lipschitz-free space) is the completion of the linear span of elementary molecules with respect to the Arens-Eells norm
$$
\|{m}\|_{AE} := \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n  |{a_i}| d(p_i,q_i) \colon m = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_{p_iq_i} \right\},
$$

where $d(p,q)$ is the distance between $p,q \in X$.

The dual of the Arens-Eells space is the $Lip_0(X)$ space of all Lipschitz functions on $X$ vanishing at $e$ equipped with the following norm
$$
\|f\|_{Lip_0} := Lip(f),
$$
where $Lip(f)$ denotes the Lipschitz constant.

*Schauder bases.* Let $U$ be a Banach space. A countable system $\{u_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N} \subset U$ is called a basis (or Schauder basis) if for any $u \in U$ there exists a unique sequence of coefficient functionals $\{c_i(u)\}_{i\in\mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R$ such that
$$
 u =\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i(u) u_i
$$
and the sum converges strongly. The coefficient functionals can be represented with a system $\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N} \subset U^*$ in the dual of $U$ and
$$
 u =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle v_i,u\rangle  u_i,
$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ denotes the duality pairing. It is easy to check that the system $\{u_i,v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is *biorthogonal*, i.e.
$$
 \langle v_j,u_i\rangle  = \delta_{ij}
$$
holds, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

NB: Not all separable Banach spaces have a basis (Enflo, 1973). However, most "common" spaces do.

**Question 1**

Does the Arens-Eells space over a compact metric space $X$ have a Schauder basis and if it does, how can it be expressed using elementary molecules?

**Thoughts**
One would think that elementary molecules
$$
m_{ij} := \delta_{p_i} - \delta_{p_j}
$$
supported on the countable dense system $\{p_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N} \subset X$ (which exists because $X$ is separable) would form  a basis. Let $\{f_{ij}\}_{i,j\in\mathbb N} \subset Lip_0(X)$ be the corresponding coefficients functionals. The biorthogonality condition would then imply that
$$
\langle f_{ij},m_{kl}\rangle  = f_{ij}(p_k) - f_{ij}(p_l) = 0 \quad \text{for $(i,j) \neq (k,l)$}
$$
and
$$
\langle f_{ij},m_{ij}\rangle = f_{ij}(p_i) - f_{ij}(p_j) = 1,
$$
which is a condition I struggle to interpret, epsecially since $(p_k,p_l)$ can be arbitrary close to $(p_i,p_j)$.

Any help will be much appreciated.

$\quad$

**Update**

Having read the [Godefroy&Ozawa paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0847) suggested in the comments below, I realised that the situation is subtler than I thought. In the generality I initially asked the question, the answer is "no" -- the space may fail the Approximation Propoerty and hence not have a basis. However, in special cases, the Approximation Property (and even the Bounded Approximation Property) is guaranteed -- for example, if $X$ is a doubling metric space ([Lancien&Pernecka](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1583)). This does not imply the existence of a basis, however (although [Borel-Mathurin](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.443.1825&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows existence of a Schauder decomposition in $AE(\mathbb R^n)$ -- a related, but as far as I understand weaker property).

Let me now ask a more specific question.

**Question 2**

Let $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact set (obviously, a doubling metric space). Does $AE(X)$ have a basis and if yes, how is it expressed using elementary molecules?

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's Eells (two L's)

Comment: The paper "Free Banach spaces and the approximation properties" by G. Godefroy and N. Ozawa (Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 142, No. 5, 1681-1687 (2014)) gives an example of a Lipschitz free space over a compact metric space without the approximation property, in particular this space fails to have a Schauder basis. See [Zbl 1291.46013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1291.46013).

Comment: There is an arxiv version of the [Godefroy-Ozawa paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0847). The required classical fact that every separable Banach space is the closure of the span of a compact convex set has been asked about before [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/122504).

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks, corrected

Comment: @DirkWerner, RobertFurber thank you both for the reference!

Comment: One more thing: the coefficient functionals are always continuous, hence a basis in your terminology is the same as a Schuder basis.

Comment: @DirkWerner I took the terminology from Heil, A Basis Theory Primer. I don’t quite remember now why he had to make this distinction. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: On page 131 of his book, Heil says, ``In Theorem 4.13 we will prove the nontrivial fact that every basis for a Banach space is a Schauder basis.'' It is not clear to me why he makes the distinction basis / Schauder basis to begin with.

Comment: @DirkWerner Oh :) Thanks! That's indeed a bit strange. I'll update the post.

Comment: The natural vector space basis of the uncompleted space of molecules is $\{\delta_p - \delta_e: p\in X, p \neq e\}$ (not all the elementary molecules, that's too much). But it will only be a Schauder basis for the completion $AE(X)$ if $X$ is uniformly discrete.

Comment: However, if $X$ is infinite, compact, and has finite Assouad dimension (in particular, any infinite compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $0 < \alpha < 1$ then $AE(X^\alpha)$ is linearly homeomorphic to $l^1$ (Theorem 8.49 in my book).

Comment: Comment 1: If you ask a new question, please start a new post and don't modify the existing one by adding ``of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$''.

Comment: Comment 2: Relevant papers for Question 2: 
Pernecká, Eva; Smith, Richard J., The metric approximation property and Lipschitz-free spaces over subsets of $\mathbb R^N$; J. Approx. Theory 199, 29-44 (2015). [Zbl 1333.46017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1333.46017), Hájek, Petr; Pernecká, Eva, On Schauder bases in Lipschitz-free spaces. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 416, No. 2, 629-646 (2014). [Zbl 1319.46010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1319.46010) and other papers by Eva Pernecka

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you! Is there a concrete description of the set of molecules that will correspond to the natural basis in $\ell^1$? For $X = [-1,1]^n$ with basepoint $0$ I could imagine something like a sequence of tensor products of $\{-1+\frac{1}{k},...,1-\frac{1}{k}\}$ for $k=2,...$ (i.e. sequence of grids on the hypercube with different mesh sizes). Perhaps the grids would have to be non-uniform depending on $\alpha$ (the exponent in the metric). Could something like this work?

Comment: @DirkWerner Re comment 1: ok, will be more careful next time, sorry

Comment: @Yuri: I'm not sure, I'd have to think about it ...

Comment: @DirkWerner Re Comment 2: Many thanks for these references! This settles the question about the existence of a basis (if $X$ is convex and bounded or has no-empty interior). But none of the proofs are constructive -- is there a concrete representation of this basis? [Cuth et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03966) show a representation of $AE(X)$ as a quotient space of $L^1(X,R^n)$ (for $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ non-empty convex open) -- could this help?